# How to change the content in a dropdown button when not selected

Tags: python-3.x, flet

My question is how do i change the content, value (call as you want) when the dropdown button is not selected or when i select another dropdown button. Example:

I have two dropdown buttons, first one you can select the options: "register supplier" and "list suppliers", when i dont select one of those options, there is a hint text called "supplier", when i select one option, the hint text disappear.

But, when i selected the other dropdown button called "stock", the option selected before in the dropdown button "supplier" doesnt disappear.

[image]

Thanks!

I tried to use on_blur and on_change, but was not successful.

Comment: Share your sample code that is not wokring